# Clicking Through Multiple Rows of Radio Buttons Using Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working with a table on a web page with X rows. Each row represents a requester either asking for something to be granted or to be revoked. The purpose of this automation is to auto-approve granting or revocation. The following code works, but - strangely - only for the first occurrence of a grant or revoke respectively:

```
            var table = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(@"//*[@id=""span_pending_approvals""]/form/table/tbody"));
            var rows = table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));

            var rowCount = 1;

            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                if (row.Text.Contains("Grant"))
                {
                    var requester = row.Text.Split(' ')[3];
                    row.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@value='approve']")).Click();
                }
                else if (row.Text.Contains("Revoke"))
                {
                    row.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@value='revoke']")).Click();
                }

                rowCount++;
            }
```

The output of this amounts to:

```
Amy - Grant[X] Wait[]
Andy - Grant[] Wait[]
Anthony - Grant[] Wait[]
Brad - Revoke[X] Wait[]
Beth - Revoke[] Wait[]
Bort - Revoke[] Wait[]
```

When what I want is:

```
Amy - Grant[X] Wait[]
Andy - Grant[X] Wait[]
Anthony - Grant[X] Wait[]
Brad - Revoke[X] Wait[]
Beth - Revoke[X] Wait[]
Bort - Revoke[X] Wait[]
```

Thoughts on why this only works on the first occurrence of each option? When I step through with a debugger I can see the .Click(); being processed as expected for each row, but it only actually registers on the webpage for the first occurrences of "Grant" or "Revoke."

Comment: Try changing this line `row.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@value='approve']")).Click();` to `row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//input[@value='approve']")).Click();`

Comment: And `row.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@value='revoke']")).Click();` this line to `row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//input[@value='revoke']")).Click();`. Just limiting the scope to the current row rather the entire dom using `.` at the beginning of the xpath under row.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the script as below.

```
foreach (var row in rows)
       {
            if (row.Text.Contains("Grant"))
            {
                var requester = row.Text.Split(' ')[3];
                row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//input[@value='approve']")).Click();
            }
            else if (row.Text.Contains("Revoke"))
            {
                row.FindElement(By.XPath(".//input[@value='revoke']")).Click();
            }

            rowCount++;
        }
```

Just limiting the scope to the current row rather the entire dom using . at the beginning of the xpath under row

Comment: moved the answer from comment to here. Please accept the solution, if you feel the issue is resolved. And feel free to upvote :-)